# In Protractor, how can I skip failed test cases and continue remaining test cases

Tags: protractor

For example, in a set of 10 test cases, one test in particular expects a condition which is failing.

In this case how can I stop executing that test case further, or should I continue to execute the remaining test cases?

Comment: Raazil, are you getting exceptions when your test fails? If that is the case then you will need to gracefully handle those exceptions in your test. Once you handler those exceptions it will not stop your next test execution.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine supports `pending()` function.

If you call pending function in your specs, the spec will be marked pending.In your case one of the expectation is failing so you could put pending function before that!

```
describe('test', function() {
it('skip this spec', function() {
if (someSkipCheck()) {
  pending();
}
expect(1).toBe(2); // this expect is failing
});
```

For more details you can refer the jasmine pending function - http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Pending_Specs

Comment: I think this will work when you know which test is failing. However, Raazil is asking "if a particular test fails, then it should continue to run next set of tests"

Answer (score 0):

skipping specific "it"s:  by adding x in the beginning => "xit"

skipping all "it"s:   add x in the beginning of the "describe" => "xdescribe"

running only specific "it"s: by adding f in the beginning => "fit"

running a specific "describe":   add f in the beggining => "fdescribe"